# Modify and Check Data while using Bulk Insert from CSV file - SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm using method below inserting Data from csv file into SQL.

```
BULK
INSERT tblMember
FROM 'F:\target.txt'
WITH
(
DATAFILETYPE='widechar',
CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\ErrorRows.csv',
)
GO
```

I need to do two things. First check if All Chars in Column One of CSV file for each row are only Digit and if yes Insert it. and Also I need to add a specific Word before these chars while inserting.

```
01 - 123,M,A,USA
02 - H24,N,Z,USA
```

I need to only insert row one, Because Column One is only Digit numbers '123', and I need to add "D" before this numbers and then insert it into SQL. so we have something like this is SQL after insertion:

```
"D123","M","A","USA"
```

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider a sample CSV(in C Drive) file `target-c.txt` which contain four lines of data.(Notice i have use `target-c.txt` not `target.txt`)

```
123,M,A,USA
H24,N,Z,USA
H25,N,V,USA
456,M,U,USA
```

Now create a Non-XML Format File(in C Drive) named it `targetFormat.fmt`. and populate the file in following way

```
9.0  
4  
1       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","     1     Col1               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  
2       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","     2     Col2               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  
3       SQLCHAR       0       100       ","     3     Col3               ""  
4       SQLCHAR       0       100     "\r\n"  4     Col4               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Please Be Careful with this formatting.Click this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx) if you want to read more about Non-XML Format File.The basic example would be like this.
[image]
**Please change the format file according to your need.(like DataType, ChaterLength etc.)**

I have created a sample table `tblMember` (please change according to your way, like column name , datatype etc. Remember you have to change the `targetFormat.fmt` file too)

```
CREATE TABLE tblMember   
   (  
   Col1 nvarchar(50),  
   Col2 nvarchar(50) ,  
   Col3 nvarchar(50) ,   
   Col4 nvarchar(50)   
   );
```

Then Use the following query for bulk-insert according to your way(**its add a character "D" in front of Col1 with integer value**)

```
INSERT INTO tblMember(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)  
(
select 'D'+t1.Col1 AS Col1,t1.Col2,t1.Col3,t1.Col4 
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\target-c.txt'
        , formatfile = 'C:\targetFormat.fmt'
        , firstrow = 1) as t1
where  t1.Col1  not like '%[^0-9]%' --Not Like Letter Number mixed (123, 456)
UNION 
select t1.Col1,t1.Col2,t1.Col3,t1.Col4 
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\target-c.txt'
        , formatfile = 'C:\targetFormat.fmt'
        , firstrow = 1) as t1
where  t1.Col1   like '%[^0-9]%'--Like Letter Number mixed (H24, H25)
)
```

Now if you select your table you will get this (i have tried and its working fine)
[image]

**Here is your answer** You can ordered the column if you want to. its very easy, just hold the query in a first bracket and order it or format it according your way.